# Expectation of a function with respect to $\mu$ is zero, implies function is $\mu$-almost surely zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $\mu$ is a probability measure and $K$ a Markov kernel, on the same space. I feel like the following statement is true:
$$
\forall\, \text{measurable } A\,:\, \quad \quad \text{if }\left(\int K(x, A) \mu(dx) = 0\right)\implies \left(K(\cdot, A) = 0 \text{ for } \mu\text{-almost every }x\right)
$$
Notice that $A$ is fixed and I am saying that whenver the LHS holds, then must the RHS. I could not prove it formally, however.

## Attempted Proof

I'll call the measurable space $(X, \mathcal{X})$. The statement on the RHS means
$$
\mu\left(\left\{x\in X\,:\, K(x, A) = 0\right\}\right) = 1.
$$
I can write this statement as follows
$$
\int_X \mathbf{1}_{\{0\}}(K(x, A)) \mu(dx) = 1 \qquad \text{ or } \qquad \int_X \mathbf{1}_{(0,1]}(K(x, A)) \mu(dx) = 0
$$
But I am unsure how to get either of these from the LHS.

Comment: Isn't $K$ non-negative? Have you studied basic measure theory yet?

Comment: @geetha290krm Yes it's non-negative. And I know that intuitively one can say: since $K$ is non-negative and has zero expectation under $\mu$, then the set of points where $K$ is strictly positive must have measure 0 under $\mu$. 

And I totally get the intuition. But I want to show it mathematically

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the more general result in measure theory, if $f\geq 0$ and $\int_X fd\mu = 0$ then for $\mu(dx)$ almost every $x\in X$ we have $f(x)=0$.

Proof: Use Markov inequality :

For all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ we have $$\mu(\{x\in X \mid f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n} \}) \leq n\int_X f(x)\mu(dx) = 0$$

Doing the countable union over all $n\geq 1$ we obtain that $$\mu(\{x \in X \mid f(x) > 0\}) = 0$$ as wished.

Apply this to $f = K(\;.\;, A)$